# PHP If Statement Logic

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, logical-operators

I am a bit stuck on an if statement on my PHP code.
I know this is probably a basic question for most of you out there, but i am stuck, and i would like some assistance.

I have 2 variables $max and $ min, which i have to compare with 2 other max and mins called $valor and $minimo in order to check if they are meeting somewhere.
What i basically have is a set of values like min=20 and max=30.

I want to compare those with the other max and min, and check if somewhere the values meet, like if the min of the second one is 29. I want it to enter the if statement.

Here's the statement i got right now. 
But it's not working, and i just can't get the logic on it. 
Any help?

EDIT: Added an example of what i am trying to achieve in the comments.

```
if ($min >= $valor && $min <= $minimo || $max >= $valor && $max <= $minimo)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
else
    {
        $queryq = "INSERT INTO precos_area (id_tecido,area_minima,area_maxima,preco) VALUES ('".$id_tipo."', '".$min."', '".$max."', '".$price."')";
        $resultsq = mysql_query($queryq) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: || $max >= $valor && $max <= $minimo) is max ever goig to be Bigger than valor AND smaller than minimo at the same time?

Comment: My idea is for the values from one max and one min, not to intertwine with the ones of the other.
Imagine a line. One max and one min show a segment to be painted. The other shows another segment which has to be painted with a different colour. My wish is for an if that checks if they ever cross, in order to do a statement if they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling the 2nd max and min are the wrong way round

```
if (($min >= $minimo && $min <= $valor ) || ($max >= $minimo && $max <= $valor ))
```

EDIT - to catch the situation that gview mentions you probably should check both ranges. This will then catch a situation where one range is completely within another range:-

```
if (($min >= $minimo && $min <= $valor ) 
|| ($max >= $minimo && $max <= $valor )
|| ($minimo >= $min && $minimo <= $max ) 
|| ($valor >= $min && $valor <= $max ))
```

Comment: What about the case where $min < $minimo AND $max > $valor.  The lines overlap in that case, but your logic would not find it true.  Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (($min >= $valor && $min <= $minimo) || ($max >= $valor && $max <= $minimo))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried grouping them. But it's still not working. Can someone help me out a bit on the logic on this? I made a comment on my main question further explaining what i am trying to achieve

Comment: can you define your values here please .

Comment: For example. $min is 10 and $max is 20. I want to check if whatever values are inserted on $minimo and $valor don't cross with those. Kinda like trying to paint 2 different areas with different colours. They can't cross anywhere in between. So $minimo can't be between 10 and 20, nor can $valor be in those values too

Comment: Kickstart solved it first. But thanks alot for your help too. You solved the 1st part of the problem too, so i'm upvoting your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
<?php

$min = 10;
$max = 20;
$valor = 25;
$minimo = 30;

if (($min >= $minimo && $min <= $valor ) || ($max >= $minimo && $max <= $valor )) {
print "win";
}

else {
print "lose";
}

?>
```